# How can I exploit a segfault and run a shell command?

Tags: c, security, shellcode

Following this: [How can I exploit a buffer overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44556590/how-can-i-exploit-a-buffer-overflow)

I have a code compiled using `-fno-stack-protector`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void shellcode(){
    printf("\n Reached shellcode!");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char buf[3];
    sprintf(buf, "%s", argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

but unable to execute the `shellcode` function.

Like in that post i am using:

```
python -c 'print "A"*27+"\x49\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"' > input
```

```
./a < input
```

Get a segfault at:

```
./a 12345678901
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

but nothing happens.

my main goal is to execute `ls` on linux os instead of `shellcode` function. but right now nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential problems here:

1. By using `sprintf(.., argv[1])`, you seem to be expecting input from argv. But `./a < input` directs the file to STDIN
2. ASLR could screw your exploit up. Meaning that you don't know if the address is correct.

It's very difficult to answer such questions without having the binary (a) itself, or at least the Makefile.

If I were you, I would work with a debugger (GDB is great) until the exploit works. But it's worth noting that with ASLR, it would be tough.

Comment: (Tangentially, saving a temporary input in a file is a very un-Unixy thing to do; use a pipe or a command substitution.)

Comment: @malkaroee Just starting to learn about sec, could you please tell what should i look particularly in gdb?